# database automatically gets deleted many time

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My mysql database gets deleted automatically
 when I checked the error log I found this error

**ec4 InnoDB: FTS Optimize Removing table noisepollution/#sql2-186c-1e**

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Could you please elaborate, what you have done to the table prior. The error message only comes when it encounters problems with the table.

Answer (score 0):

`#sql...` is a temp table built for supporting `ALTER` or some other action.  Normally it would be automatically removed (or renamed).  But if there is a system crash, or certain other errors (maybe: out of disk space), the file is left around.  The message you gave sounds as if it came from a Cloud service that is trying to clean up the mess.

In any case, please provide the actions that happens just before the problem